# sbt set java options in Dynamic Task

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to write task which takes input argument, pass it to testOnly task and execute. It works perfectly, but I cannot set system propertis in this task, which will be visible in test. This properties should not affect other tasks and should be visible only in this custom task.

Here is my code sample

```
lazy val myTestOnly = InputKey[Unit]("myTestOnly", "test only with special sys prop")

val myTestOnlyTask = myTestOnly := {
  Def.inputTaskDyn {
    val args: Seq[String] = spaceDelimited("").parsed

    javaOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Dfoo=bar") // does not work
    testOptions += Tests.Setup(() => System.setProperty("foo", "bar")) //does not work
    System.setProperty("foo", "bar") // does not work

    (testOnly in Test).toTask(" " + args.head)
  }.evaluated
}
```

When I run in sbt console

```
 myTestOnly com.sampleTest
```

testOnly executes but "foo" property is not visible

So the qustion is how to set property in task definition which will be visible in test runtime only for current task?

Answer (score 0):

in build.sbt:

```
val currentTimestamp: String =
  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date())
val targetDir
  : String = baseDirectory + "/project/target/mtd/" + currentTimestamp

javaOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Ddynamic_dir_to_set=" + targetDir)
```

and `sbt test` will have guaranteed value for the dynamic_dir_to_set env var.

Couple of theory links to go trough:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Forking.html#change-working-directory
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins-and-Best-Practices.html